# Virtualenv - Cleaning up unused package installations

Tags: django, virtualenv

So I have been developing my first django web application over the past few months and I have installed a number of packages that I wanted to try and use to solve some of my problems. However, some of these packages I installed, tried to use, failed, and then never uninstalled.

Is there a way to see what packages my application is using from the list given from "pip freeze"?

That way I can uninstall some of the clutter in my application. Is it a huge disadvantage to have this clutter?

In future development I will uninstall packages right away if I do not use them. So lesson learned :).

Comment: Just search your project for occurences of `import` and compare with pip freeze? It's not a big deal to have unused packages installed. However it will be an issue when you try to install your app somewhere. For that you should always have a list of required packages (with versions) in your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method I use is with my `requirements.txt` files. From the root of my Django project, I create a `requirements/` directory with the following files in it:

```
requirements/
    base.txt
    dev.txt
    prod.txt
    temp.txt
```

`base.txt` contains packages to be used in all environments such as `Django==1.8.6`.

Then dev would include base and other packages, and might look like:

```
-r base.txt
coverage==4.0.2
```

Then `temp.txt` includes `dev.txt` and contains packages I'm not sure I'll use permanently:

```
-r dev.txt
temp_package==1.0
git+https://github.com/django/django.git#1014ba026e879e56e0f265a8d9f54e6f39843348
```

Then I can blow away the entire virtualenv and reinstall it from the appropriate requirements file like so:

```
pip install -r requirements/dev.txt
```

Or, to include the temp_package I'm testing:

```
pip install -r requirements/temp.txt
```

That's just how I do it, and it helps keep my sandbox separate from the finished product.

Comment: Ahh, that's a cool way of doing that. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Ah, one more thing - it is best to always pin to a version number or commit. I'll amend my answer with an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, you could use isort and run `isort myproject/* --diff` to get a list of proposed changes isort would make to your project.

In the proposed changes, it list imports that are not used. From that, you could take a look at packages installed in your virtual environment and start removing them with pip. This is assuming you did not remove the import statements, which may not be the case.

Another way would be to create a new env and attempt to run your app. Use error messages to get the packages you need until your app runs. Not pretty, but it would work.